# Trouble creating table in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a table using this command in MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE tutorial_info(
     tutorial_id INT NOT_NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
     tutorial_title VARCHAR(100) NOT_NULL,
     tutorial_author VARCHAR(100) NOT_NULL,
     submission_date TIMESTAMP
   );
```

I just cut and paste the code into the terminal but I am getting the error:

*You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT_NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,      tutorial_title VARCHAR(100) NOT_NULL, ' at line 1*

Not sure what is going on here. Could someone give me a pointer to what I might be doing wrong here? Thanks

Comment: `NOT NULL` is two words, not one.  This seems like a simple typographical error, so I'm voting to close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `NOT_NULL` to `NOT NULL` as:

```
CREATE TABLE tutorial_info(
     tutorial_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
     tutorial_title VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
     tutorial_author VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
     submission_date TIMESTAMP
   );
```

Answer (score 1):

Use not null without `_`

```
CREATE TABLE tutorial_info(
     tutorial_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
     tutorial_title VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
     tutorial_author VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
     submission_date TIMESTAMP
   );
```